# PHP Select tags problems

Tags: php, mysql

I just started learning some PHP and SQL for my uni. I got everything figured out somehow but there have been a few problems. So what I'm doing is getting the values of a '`select`' dropdown dynamically from the Database.

```
$sql = "SELECT catDesc, catID from Categories";
$queryResult = $dbConn->query($sql);

echo '<select name="eventcat" size="1" class="dropdownstyle" id="catevent" required/>';
echo '<option value="choose">Event Category</option>';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult)){
    $xx = $row['catDesc'];
    $id = $row['catID']; 
    echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $xx . '</option>';
}
```

So this above piece of code works. However. After the user submits the form. It redirects to a new page. "admin-process.php". I want this page to somehow get the value of the variable **"$xx"**. I know how to get the value by using this method:-

```
$id = isset($_REQUEST['eventcat']) ? $_REQUEST['eventcat'] : null;
```

However, this displays the id of the option. Not the main thing that I need. The id and the value differ here. So in short. How do I get the name of the option tag?

Comment: Generally you'd use the ID to get the rest of the information from the database.  The ID should uniquely identify the record.

Comment: @David yeah but what I'm supposed to do is to take all the data from the form and insert it into the DB. Also I just need the catID to be entered in the DB. Not the catDesc. I just want to display catDesc on the next confirmation page you know. So I kind of need both of them accessible to me.

Comment: So find the `catDesc` by quering your database with __known__ `catID`.

Comment: Well there are accessible if you query the desc again from the database ? `SELECT catDESC from Categories WHERE catID =?`

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the name of the option tag.

You don't.  At least not directly.  The only value posted as part of the form is the selected *value* from that element.  In this case your `catID` value.

That value should uniquely identify the record which was selected.  (If it doesn't, that's a different problem.)  With that value you can then [query the database](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to get the rest of the information from the uniquely identified record.  It may contain one more field, several more fields, joins with other tables, etc.  Doesn't really matter what it contains, as long as you can uniquely identify it based on that ID.

So on your next page (`admin-process.php`) you'd read the posted `catID` value and use it in a query to your `Categories` table.  That query should return one record, from which you'd display the additional data.